# innerHTML sometimes works, sometimes doesn't?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

The text at the top of this page http://acsoundstudio.com/bb/2520dip8/ is supposed to change when you click Capacitor 10pf and it does that, but then clicking on 39pf changes the image in the background, but does not make the top change from 10pf to 39pf. It stays at 10pf.

I'm not really sure what's causing this. Here is some sample code:

HTML:

```
<li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Capacitors | pF</a>

        <ul class="dl-submenu">
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick='topCap1()'>10pf</a></li>

          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick='topCap2()'>39pf</a></li>

          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick='topCap3()'>47pf</a></li>

          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick='topCap4()'>1000pf</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

JS:

```
function topCap1() {
  document.getElementById('bbtop').src = "img/2520dip8_c1_10pf.png";
  document.getElementById('bbdefine').innerHTML = "10pf Capacitor";
}

function topCap2() {
  document.getElementById('bbtop').src = "img/2520dip8_c2_39pf.png";
  document.getElementById('bbdefine').innerHTML = "39pf Capacitor";
}

function topCap3() {
  document.getElementById('bbtop').src = "img/2520dip8_c4-5_47pf.png";
  document.getElementById('bbdefine').innerHTML = "47pf Capacitors";
}

function topCap4() {
  document.getElementById('bbtop').src = "img/2520dip8_c6_1000pf.png";
  document.getElementById('bbdefine').innerHTML = "1000pf Capacitor";
}
```

Also, if you have any ideas for simplifying this code that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not reproducible: http://jsbin.com/acecaLEs/1/edit

Comment: try using `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: weird. Maybe because it's in a submenu?

Comment: It works if you remove class 'blink' from #bbdefine.

Comment: very nice. textContent worked. I guess the style was interfering...

Comment: If you want to simplify, I really suggest using jQuery.

Comment: Please, no one listen to that comment ^^^^

Comment: `$("#idSelector").attr("src","enterTheNewSRChere");` can be used instead of `document.getElementById('bbtop').src = "img/2520dip8_c4-5_47pf.png";` and `$("#idSelector").html("someTextHere");` will do the job.

Comment: @Luxelin Yes, I'm quite aware. It's also 8 lines of unminified javascript....and you just recommended adding the MASSIVE jquery library to simplify it.

Comment: The page actually already has jQuery on it... http://acsoundstudio.com/bb/2520dip8/

Comment: he said simplify the code, not shorten the entire package =)

Comment: but, yeah, as @jaksco said above, he already has a minified version of jQuery on the page, so it wouldn't be adding anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a much lighter approach. Just add in the background logic. **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/acecaLEs/2/edit)**

```
<div id="bbtop"></div>
<div id="bbdefine"></div>
<ul class="dl-submenu">
  <li><a>10pf</a></li>
  <li><a>39pf</a></li>
  <li><a>47pf</a></li>
  <li><a>1000pf</a></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
var bbdefine = document.getElementById('bbdefine');

var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dl-submenu li a');

for (var i=0; i<elems.length; ++i) {
  elems[i].addEventListener('click', clickFunc);
}

function clickFunc(event) {
  bbdefine.textContent = this.textContent+' Capacitor';
}
```

Inline JS (like onclick and the js hrefs in your html) has never been a good practice. Instead, attach the event listeners with javascript. I recommend you read some of these results: **[Why is inline js bad?](https://www.google.com/search?q=Why%20is%20inline%20js%20bad?)**

If you need to support older browsers, test this code and check the console for errors, then shim anything that isn't available. `addEventListener` hasn't always been around, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't really get this line `var bbdefine = document.getElementById('bbtop');` would I make the href link to the png file?

Comment: @jaksco that was a speed coding error on my part :) Obviously, `bbdefine` should refer to the `bbdefine` element. You need to also get the other element reference and manipulate it however you need. You could add `data-src="path/here"` on the links, then get the value with `this.getAttribute('data-src')`.